# What is the Meaning of "で" in this sentence? マイクは冬休みでわくわくしています。

Tags: particles, particle-で

The sentence:

> マイクは冬休みでわくわくしています。

Is it "Mike is thrilled *for* winter vacation"?

If I change it to マイクは冬休み**に**わくわくしています, does it become "Mike is thrilled in winter vacation"?

I learned that "で" can mean **in**, e.g. "I make food **in** the restaurant", レストラン**で**料理をしています; **at**, "I'm **at** school", 私は学校**で**います; or **by**, "I will go to school **by** car", 車**で**学校に行く

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [で](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A7/#je-50708) or [に](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%AB/#je-56984) in the sentence won't change the meaning. Both would be understood as *Mike is excited **because of** winter vacation*.

Both で and に can mean a reason or cause. The following is from the entry に. All the に used here can be replaced by で without changing the meaning (much).

> 6〔理由，原因〕for；with
>
> 恥ずかしさに赤面した 
> She blushed for shame.
>
> うれしさに躍り上がった 
> He danced for [with] joy.
>
> 寒さに震えた 
> They shivered with cold.
>
> 彼らは飢えに苦しんでいた 
> They were suffering from hunger.
>
> 警報に驚いた 
> We were startled by the alarm.

On the other hand, 彼はがんで死んだ (*He died of cancer*., で is used for a cause) can't be ×彼はがんに死んだ. So it ultimately depends on the verb whether で/に is used.

---

BTW 私は学校でいます is not acceptable. It should be 私は学校にいます.